# ACCESS_METHODS_HOBT_VIRTUAL_ROOT event

Tags: sql-server, performance

According to reputable websites:

ACCESS_METHODS_HOBT_VIRTUAL_ROOT

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-latch-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
access_methods_hobt_virtual_root    used to synchronize access to the root page abstraction of an internal b-tree.

paul randal
https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/most-common-latch-classes-and-what-they-mean/
access_methods_hobt_virtual_root
this latch is used to access the metadata for an index that contains the page id of the index’s root page.
contention on this latch can occur when a b-tree root page split occurs (requiring the latch in ex mode)
and threads wanting to navigate down the b-tree (requiring the latch in sh mode) have to wait. this could
be from very fast population of a small index using many concurrent connections, with or without page
splits from random key values causing cascading page splits (from leaf to root).

How do I tune SQL Server to limit this wait type?

Comment: We found over 21 indexes that were more than 50% fragmented.

Comment: Are you actually experiencing this Wait Type?   Your levels of index fragmentation do not necessarily correspond to seeing this Wait Type as the fragmentation is shown at the leaf level rather than the root level of the b-tree